# hadoop version command gives error related to java (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, hadoop

I am getting error while running the hadoop command

```
    sagar@sagar-desktop:~$ hadoop version
    Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
    Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop: line 350: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java: No  such file or directory
    Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop: line 434: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

the java and hadoop path are

```
$JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_67
$HADOOP_HOME = Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1
```

Please help me in solving these error

Comment: Compare the output of `which java` command with actual directory where you have installed java. Most probably your JAVA_HOME path is incorrect.

Comment: @Shekhar that command gives output /usr/bin/java but adding this path to env variable $JAVA_HOME doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [this Hadoop wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop). You need to set `JAVA_HOME` variable in `hadoop-env.sh` file present in hadoop/conf directory, format HDFS and then you can try `hadoop version` command.

Comment: i got the answer as i have two java versions installed and i was using one and i updated in hadoop-env.sh the other one thanks shekhar for your help