# hadoop command gives error related to java (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, hadoop

Getting the below error on running the hadoop command.

```
Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop: line 350: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java: No  such file or directory
Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop: line 434: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

the java and hadoop paths are:

```
$JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_75
$HADOOP_HOME = Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1
```

I have Java 1.6 and 1.7 installed and I have updated the the path of Java 1.7 in hadoop-env.sh

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741973/hadoop-version-command-gives-error-related-to-java-no-such-file-or-directory) but unable to resolve the issue. Please help me out.

Comment: Are you sure this path (`/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java`) exists?

Comment: Hi Francesco, yes the path exists.

Comment: Performed a new installation. Everything seems fine now. Wish I had found out what was wrong. Appreciate your reply Francesco.

Comment: I'm happy now everything works fine, happy *hadooping*!

Comment: Please delete or self answer the question.